# Mount encrypted Hdd

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, encryption, luks

I had some issues with my Hdd that is encrypted. I KNOW the passphrase, but I might have messed up something else (maybe LUKS header?) and now even with passphrase, I get an error:

```
Error unlocking /dev/sda5: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error unlocking /dev/sda5: Command-line `cryptsetup luksOpen "/dev/sda5" "luks-b1551a96-1979-4b0b-898c-e58c887e785a" ' exited with non-zero exit status 2: No key available with this passphrase.
```

with

```
sudo hexdump -C -n 512 /dev/sda5
```

I get:

```
00000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 01  61 65 73 00 00 00 00 00  |LUKS....aes.....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  78 74 73 2d 70 6c 61 69  |........xts-plai|
00000030  6e 36 34 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |n64.............|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00  |........sha256..|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 10 00 00 00 00 40  |...............@|
00000070  2a b7 6a 58 2e aa a9 f4  5e 87 9a 4b 76 8c 5e 60  |*.jX....^..Kv.^`|
00000080  8f f8 5a b9 40 2f 3c a5  1d d7 cb f9 71 22 64 7c  |..Z.@/<.....q"d||
00000090  e7 8a e4 ca 17 9b f2 fc  78 29 71 51 10 b0 f6 2c  |........x)qQ...,|
000000a0  c5 1d 21 21 00 01 1b b1  62 31 35 35 31 61 39 36  |..!!....b1551a96|
000000b0  2d 31 39 37 39 2d 34 62  30 62 2d 38 39 38 63 2d  |-1979-4b0b-898c-|
000000c0  65 35 38 63 38 38 37 65  37 38 35 61 00 00 00 00  |e58c887e785a....|
000000d0  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 08 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000100  00 ac 71 f3 00 04 7a c9  00 4f 94 1f b4 a5 8d 6a  |..q...z..O.....j|
00000110  8f c9 2d 7d ee f9 a2 20  db 7c d9 e8 8d d5 8d 35  |..-}... .|.....5|
00000120  5e 55 1d dc 06 bc f7 91  00 00 02 00 00 00 0f a0  |^U..............| ....
```

Since I do know the correct passphrase/key and the HDD is fine, is there a way to mount it?